# unit test on delete operation

Tags: unit-testing, grails

this is delete operation where i want a unit test and

```
def deleteRoutineTable()
    {   def deleteRoutineTableId=params.id;
       def routineTable=RoutineTable.get(deleteRoutineTableId);
        routineTable.delete()
        redirect(action: "routineTable")
    }
```

and this is test code...but this shows error..as

```
def newRoutintable=new RoutineTable(id:1,name: "routine",institution:1,endTime: new Date(),startTime: new Date())
                newRoutintable.save(flush:true)
                newRoutintable.list().size()+1
                when:
               controller.deleteRoutineTable()
                then:newRoutintable.list().size()-1

        }
```

Failure:  |

```
testDelete(routine.RoutineTableControllerSpec)
 |
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method delete() on null object
    at routine.RoutineTableController.deleteRoutineTable(RoutineTableController.groovy:54)
    at routine.RoutineTableControllerSpec.testDelete(RoutineTableControllerSpec.groovy:60)
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to have a unit test and not an integration test? Just move this test into the integration test folder and try it again.